# forge properties.sqlite vs viewable json for revit type parameters

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

My understanding was that the derivative properties were base on the PropertyDatabase. However it seems in Revit type parameters (as opposed to instance parameters), for example used in a custom family based on shared parameters seem to be handled differently.. They appear in the derivative properties of the {3D} view, but not in the PropertyDatabase. Why aren't they in the PropertyDatabase as well, where else is that information kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you're accessing the properties via the [GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) endpoint, through Forge Viewer APIs, or any other way, the data is still the same.

You are correct though that the "inherited properties" are handled slightly differently. For example, in case of Revit documents, certain properties may be defined on the "family type" node, and it's up to the consumer of this data to make these properties visible on "instances" as well. It's possible that the Model Derivative endpoint handles this, including the family metadata in each instance as well.

Btw. we've recently discovered this issue in Forge Viewer's `search` function as well. When searching for a specific string, the method would only return "family type" objects as matches, but non of their instances. This is currently being addressed by the engineering team.

Comment: Thanks Petr! That's really helpful :) I see the object in question has a parent that is a Revit Family Type and has an instanceof_objid of an object that seems to represent the values used in that concrete instance of the family type. That seems to be it, but is it documented anywhere how to interpret this?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not documented yet. We'll get that fixed :)